# Image is not getting loaded even after a permanent save

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a profile page where we can select the image from the camera and that image will be set as the profile picture. I am saving the image in the directory I have access to and updating the UI after the image is captured. But when I'm restarting the app the captured image is no longer there and I'm seeing the default placeholder image after every restart. Here is the code for the image picker (using provider):

```
class ProfileInfoProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  // this will hold the image
  File? _imageFile;

  // this will hold the name
  late String _name;

  // method to set the profile image
  Future<void> setProfileImage({required ImageSource source}) async {
    // instantiation image picker
    ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

    // picking the image with the source selected
    XFile? pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: source);

    // if user did pick an image
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      // converting the pickedImage to the pickedImageFile
      File pickedImageFile = File(pickedImage.path);

      // getting the image name
      String imageName = pickedImage.name;

      // getting the locaiton we can store the data in
      String dirName = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;

      // copying the file to the path
      File copiedFile = await pickedImageFile.copy('$dirName/$imageName');

      // setting the image
      _imageFile = copiedFile;

      // notifying the listeners
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  // setter to set the name
  void setName(String name) {
    _name = name;

    // notifying listeners
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // getter to get the image file
  File? get getImageFile {
    return _imageFile;
  }

  // getter to get the name
  String get getName {
    return _name;
  }
}
```

Here is the drawer where I want the image:

```
class CustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      // this container is the background of the Drawer
      child: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        // this columnn will hold the First container that holds the name and the image
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // this container holds the name and the image. Using container for a different background
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 200, // the dark background height
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              // safe area to make sure that the content does not overlap with the notification bar
              child: SafeArea(
                // padding for the column
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  // this holds the actual image and name
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Consumer<ProfileInfoProvider>(
                        builder: (context, profileInfoPorivder, child) {
                          return CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 40,
                            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                            backgroundImage: profileInfoPorivder.getImageFile ==
                                    null
                                ? AssetImage('assets/images/no_profile.jpg')
                                : FileImage(profileInfoPorivder.getImageFile!)
                                    as ImageProvider,
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Dipansh Parmar',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // this list view holds different options. Wrapping it inside Expanded to give it the full remaining height
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(
                        context,
                        EditProfilePage.routeName,
                      );
                    },
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.edit,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'Edit profile',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should use a stateful widget not a stateless widget for this purpose. use setState for saving the image.

Comment: Actually, I'm using it with the provider here so I am calling notifyListeners here. It does the same work.